# Python: modify a table attribute from the options generated in another table

Tags: python, pycharm

I have created two different functions, one to create an inventory of available products:

```
    def create_piece():
            print(Colour().blue('Creating a new piece'.center(200)))
            piece_name = input(Colour().orange('Name of the piece: '))
            piece_registration = input(Colour().orange('Piece registration number: '))
            piece_date = input(Colour().orange('Date of manufacture: '))
            piece_location = input(Colour().orange('Manufacturing location: '))
            piece_price = input(Colour().orange('Price: '))

            Parts.create(Name=piece_name , Parts_registration_number=piece_registration ,
                  Date_of_manufacture=piece_date ,
                  Manufacturing_locality=piece_location , Price=piece_price ,
                  Number_of_parts_sold='0')
            print(Colour().green(('Part created satisfactorily')))
```

As you can see the option "Number_of_parts_sold" has the marker to 0.

Then I have created an option to execute purchase orders:

```
     def order_purchase():
                print(Colour().blue('Purchase order portal'.center(200))
            Seller_name = input(Colour().orange('Who are you?: '))
            number = int(input(Colour().orange('Number of items?: '))
            pieces_list=[]
            total_cost = 0
            for i in range (0, number):
                while True:
                    piece_name = input(Colour().orange('Name of the piece to buy: '))
                    try:
                        piece = Pieces.get(Pieces.Name == piece_name)
                        break
                    except DoesNotExist:
                        print(Colour().red('This piece does not currently exist in the system, ')
                    please enter a correct name.'))
                   ID = input(Colour().orange('Purchase ID: '))
                for price in Piezas.select().where(Pieces.Name == piece_name):
                    price_orders = (price.price)
                    total_cost += price_orders
                name_piece=str(name_piece)
                parts_list.append(part_name)
            Orders.create(ID_buy_orders=ID, Date_buy_orders=datetime.now(),
                              Order_Seller=Seller_name , Order_People = pieces_list,
                              Price_orders=total_cost)
            print(Colour().green('Pieces sold satisfactorily'))
```

This last function fills in another table in which it stores the number of pieces that each seller buys. However, I would like to know how to relate the second table with the first so that for each piece that is sold (generated in the tuple "lista_piezas") change the marker and add in the first table how many pieces have been sold. How could I do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: The use of Spanish (I think) is very confusing to non-Spanish speakers. Please translate your code or add some comments in English.

Comment: I have modified them. I am sorry for that

Comment: I'm not sure but I thiink that `Pieces.get(Pieces.Name == piece_name)` is wrong, you're passing a bool to the function.This kind of function calls appear in other places in your code.